# a swap partition

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, swap

I was install ubuntu 16.04 with 'install ubuntu alongside windows' option that do anythings like Partitioning by default.

But when I check the swap partition size by `swapon -s` command, this output has been shown :

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda8                               partition   58039292    0   -1
```

And here is my `free -h` command output :

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        982M         13G        130M        1.2G         14G
Swap:           60G          0B         60G
```

As you seen I have 16G ram and 60G swap partition. (and I have windows alongside ubuntu)

Is this normal to set 60G for swap partition ? (beacause it is much more than 2xram)

Comment: It is not normal. With 16GB of RAM you can completely remove the swap partition.

Comment: I don't know how big the installer makes it by default, but 60 GB is certainly bigger than you need. As a general rule, I don't recommend removing it completely, and certainly not if you intend to use suspend-to-disk; but something just slightly more than your RAM size should be perfectly adequate for a suspend-to-disk operation, or just about anything else.

Comment: RodSmith has it correct. Pilot has it wrong.

Comment: @Pilot6 **Everybody** needs a swap partition or a swapfile... no matter how much memory they have. Especially if they want to use suspend-to-disk (hibernation).

Comment: I do not have a swap and many people do not have it. It makes no sense to use hibernation with 16GB of RAM. It will be too slow anyway.

Comment: @Pilot6  With 16G RAM and no swap, all that does is to postpone the inevitable... a freeze or a crash. Try it yourself. Either load a bunch of high memory usage apps, or write a little script that eats memory, and watch what happens. I also have 16G RAM, and I've seen my swap partition in use.

Comment: I am trying it "myself" for many years. Started with 4GB of RAM, now I have 12. You can always "write a script" that will eat all swap as well. It is impossible to use all 16 GB with normal use.

Answer (score 1):

60GB is way too much swap. If you have 16 gigs of RAM you probably don't need a swap partition anyway, but generally having as much swap as you have ram is good if you have 8 gigs or less of RAM.

Comment: Everybody needs a swap partition or a swapfile... no matter how much memory they have. Especially if they want to use suspend-to-disk (hibernation).

Comment: Do not say for everybody ;-)

Comment: Yeah you actually don't technically need one